# Saving a block in instance variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

How do we declare a global(private instance variable) to accept a block in it. Do we need to synthesis it & what are the memory management implications with it.

I have a block received from a third party method which I want to save in the instance variable & use it at a later stage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an (ARC-less) example of storing a block for a completion callback after doing some work in the background:

Worker.h:

```
@interface Worker : NSObject
{
    void (^completion)(void);
}
@property(nonatomic,copy) void (^completion)(void);
- (void)workInBackground;
@end
```

Worker.m:

```
@implementation Worker
@synthesize completion;

- (void)dealloc
{
    Block_release(completion);

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)setCompletion:(void (^)(void))block
{
    if ( completion != NULL )
        Block_release(completion);

    completion = Block_copy(block);
}

- (void)workInBackground
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void)
    {
        // Do work..

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), completion);
    });
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [`Blocks Programming Topics`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH5-SW2):

> You can copy and release blocks using C functions:
>
> ```
> Block_copy();
> Block_release();
> ```
>
> If you are using Objective-C, you can send a block `copy`, `retain`, and `release` (and `autorelease`) messages.
>
> To avoid a memory leak, you must always balance a `Block_copy()` with `Block_release()`. You must balance `copy` or `retain` with `release` (or `autorelease`)—unless in a garbage-collected environment.

Comment: This is fine. Within the same controller class I want to save the block received in one method so that I could use it later in another method. How should I do that. I thought of saving block on some instance variable & then use it later.

Comment: You can't use `retain`, `release` or `autorelease` in an ARC environment either.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360998/beginsheet-block-alternative-with-arc and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701923/arc-bridge-cast-block-copy-block-release if you are using ARC.